# How to query a PyTables frame_table saved via a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, h5py

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('fname.dat')
```

So, I create/ open an existing HDFStore file:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
```

To index a subset of columns, I simply use

```
store.append('key_name', df, data_columns=['colA','colB','colZ'])
```

Apparently, `HDFStore.append()`saves pandas dataframes per default in `table` format. However, it looks like it is actually a 'frame_table' object:

```
store
```

outputs

```
 /key_name            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->3254334,ncols->14,indexers->[index],dc->[colA, colB, colZ])
```

How do I efficiently index this object?

Normally, the query would be

```
 result = [row for row in table.where('colA==22 & colB==45')]
```

But would does one do this for a `frame_table` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frame_table` - means that it's a Data Frame saved in `table` format.

You have already "indexed" `['colA','colB','colZ']` columns, when used `data_columns=['colA','colB','colZ']` parameter.

So now you can query your HDFStore as follows:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
varA = 100
varZ = 'string_value'
df = store.select('key_name', where='colA >= varA & colZ == varZ')
```

alternatively you can use `pd.read_hdf(...)` instead of `store.select(...)`

PS the answer could be much more neat if you would provide a sample and desired data sets...